How to create a subclass with a different type parameter to its parent
PEP 695 introduced a nice way to specify type parameters in a generic class.
But I find the rules around inheritance confusing. I would like to inherit from a class which specifies a type parameter, but replace the parent's type parameter with a different class.
Here is an example:
class Foo[T]:
    prop: T

    def get_prop(self) -> T:
        return self.prop


class StringFoo(Foo[str]):
    prop: str = "Hello world"

    def do_thing(self):
        reveal_type(self.get_prop())  # str


class IntFoo(Foo[int]):
    prop: int = 42

    @property
    def is_a_number(self) -> bool:
        return True

    def do_thing(self):
        reveal_type(self.get_prop())  # int

But if I want another type of Foo which inherits from IntFoo (because I want is_a_number on my new class), I try doing this:
class FloatFoo(IntFoo[float]):  # this line has the message
    def do_thing(self) -> float:
        reveal_type(self.get_prop())  # int :(
        return 42.0

But my IDE tells me:

Expected no type arguments for class "IntFoo"

I even tried this:
class FloatFoo(Foo[float], IntFoo):  # there's another message here
    prop: float = 42.0

    def do_thing(self):
        reveal_type(self.get_prop())  # float :)

But now I get:

Base classes of FloatFoo are mutually incompatible

So how can I declare a subclass of IntFoo which has all IntFoo's methods, but which has a different type parameter?

It would also be nice to understand the reasoning behind these messages. I'm not completely sure why what I'm doing isn't allowed because it feels like it could be.

IntFoo is not a generic class, you can't qualilfy it as IntFoo[float]

You an do class NewIntFoo(IntFoo): to define a subclass.

Sounds like maybe it's not possible to get a subclass of IntFoo whose self.get_prop() has a type of float.

Having thought about this for a while this seems maybe impossible: any methods of IntFoo will expect self.prop to be an int so there's no reason to expect those methods to be safely callable with some random other type in self.prop.

Would it work if the types in question were also parent-child related? In other words if the subclass of IntFoo had a type for self.prop which was a subclass of int?

Does this make sense in light of Liskov Substitutability Principle?

hmmm, yes maybe Liskov is broken by this. I think that's a short way of saying what I said about methods on IntFoo which expect self.prop to be an int. Ok, maybe this is just impossible (and even nonsensical?!)

I suggest you upgrade python 3.13.0 by this weekend. Everything has changed.
